# How to bundle a plugin which requires multiple files in order to work

Tags: aurelia

I'm facing an issue when I try to bundle [Aurelia-hammer](https://github.com/benib/aurelia-hammer) with the CLI.
The app still keeps pulling hammer-swipe.js, hammer-tap.js,... from the node_modules folder.
When I inspect the plugin's AMD structure, these are defined as global resources:

```
function configure(frameworkConfig) {
frameworkConfig.globalResources('./hammer-swipe');
frameworkConfig.globalResources('./hammer-tap');
frameworkConfig.globalResources('./hammer-press');
frameworkConfig.globalResources('./hammer-hold');}
```

Is there any way to bundle these with the CLI? I tried adding these files to the "resources" element in aurelia.json without success.

Answer (score 2):

the plugin author should export those classes: (HammerPressCustomAttribute...) so they could be traced properly. But you can dummy-import theme yourself as a workaround:

```
import { HammerPressCustomAttribute } from 'aurelia-hammer/hammer-press';
import { HammerSwipeCustomAttribute } from 'aurelia-hammer/hammer-swipe';
import { HammerTapeCustomAttribute } from 'aurelia-hammer/hammer-tap';
```

normally you have to do this as well:

```
import { HammerHoldCustomAttribute } from 'aurelia-hammer/hammer-hold';
```

but the class exported from hammer-hold.js is named *HammerPressCustomAttribute* (oops looks like copy-paste issue) so just reference the file even with a non existent class.

```
import { HammerHoldCustomAttribute } from 'aurelia-hammer/hammer-hold';
```

this should fix your problem (I hope). It's best to open an issue in the plugin repo and ask the author to export those classes (and rename the duplicate one).

Comment: I didn't get it working this way, but I decided to remove the wrapper altogether and just use vanilla hammerjs. Thanks for the help though!